# Java Repeat regular expression

Tags: java, regex, expression

I have following RegEx which should match e.g. some ids in brackets:

```
[swpf_02-7679, swpf_02-7622, ...]

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\[\\s]*?[a-z]{1,8}[0-9]*?_[0-9]{2,}\\-[0-9]+[\\s]*?\\]");
```

The goal is now to combine this pattern with "split" at "," to fit the string `[swpf_02-7679, swpf_02-7622]` and not only `[swpf_02-7679]` like the posted RegEx above.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: What's the problem with simple split?

Comment: Well...with split the string must look like this: [swpf_02-7679],[swpf_02-7640]. Otherwise I have to adjust the RegEx?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[` and `]` from the string then `split` at the `,`

Comment: Hmmm okay. But the "[]" brackets are a condition. Means that the string looks like that [..., ...] and must be checked for validation.

Comment: Ok...I can use startsWith() and endWith. Thanks @Jimadilo

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want to do I think is to just remove the '[' and ']' in front and back (use `String.subString()`), then split on comma with `String.split()` and use the regex on each individual string so returned (adjust the regex to remove the brackets of course).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that you want the bits that the id's are like "swpf_02-7622", then split on the comma, and loop through the remains, trimming as you go. Some thing like

```
List<String> cleanIds = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String id : ids.split(","))
    cleanIds.add(id.trim());
```

If you want rid of the "swpf_" bits, then id.substring(5).

Finally, to git rid of the square brackets, use id.startsWith('[') and id.endsWith(']') .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Java [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class and then just use the regex on the tokens you get out of this? You can post-process them to include the brackets you need or modify the regex slightly.

Comment: From your link:
_StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._

Answer (score 0):

As @was and @garyh already mentioned the simplest way is to remove `[]`, then split your list using `String.split("\s*,\S*"), then match each member using your pattern.

You can also match your string multiple times using start position as a end position of the previous iteration:

Pattern p = .... // your pattern in capturing brackets `()` 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

```
for (int start = 0; m.find(start); start = m.end()) {
    String element = m.group(1);
    // do what you need with the element.
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your split regex: `"\\s*,\\S*"` should be `"\\s*,\\s*"` (lowercase `s` both times). Also, your `for` loop is equivalent to `while (m.find())`; you don't need to keep track of the match position yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract all the codes in you list you could use this regular expression:

```
[^,\s\[\]]+
```

Getting all the matches from the following string:

```
[swpf_02-7679, swpf_02-762342, swpf_02-7633  ,   swpf_02-723422]
```

Would give you the following results:

```
swpf_02-7679
swpf_02-762342
swpf_02-7633
swpf_02-723422
```